# how to append values to list using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, list

how to append values to list using python3?

```
l=[]
listt=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
for i,string in enumerate(listt):
  if i == 0 :
     for j in string:
       print(j)
l.append(j)
print(l,"*******")
```

> Expected Output:

```
    ['a','b','c']*******
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is a nested list and your output is a single list pulled for the nested list, so you could accomplish this task with much less code.

```
listt=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
print (listt[0], "*******")
# outputs
['a', 'b', 'c'] *******
```